# Free Shipping using PHP Script

Tags: magento-1.9, php, free-shipping, script

I have to give free shipping order over 1000 and zipcode range between 600001 to 600010, i am using webshop matrix rate for shipping method, in this case, shopping cart pricing rule not working free shipping, so i have to plan for do custom PHP code for giving free shipping, My condition how can i give condition like subtotal is equal or greater than 1000 and zipcode between 600001 and 600010 in

> /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

How can i give free shipping using script?

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can try this way.

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface">
      <plugin name="change_shipping method" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\ShowFreeShipping"/>
   </type>
</config>
```

**ShowFreeShipping.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class ShowFreeShipping
{

 public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession){
   $this->checoutSession $checkoutSession;
 }

 public function afterEstimateByAddress(Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterfac $subject, $methods)
 {
  $quote = $this->checoutSession->getQuote();
  $postCode = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
  $totals = $quote->getTotals();      
  $subtotal = $totals['subtotal']['value'];
  foreach($methods as $key => &$method)
  {
     if($method->getMethodCode() == 'freeshipping')
     {
     //set condition whenever you want to show freeshipping or not
       if($sbutotal <= 1000)
         unset($methods[$key]);
     }
  }
 return $methods;
 }
}
```

Please make sure that you have enabled freeshipping from admin. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Here, where i can i give postal-code condition?

Comment: Please chect my updated answer, I hope it 'll work for you.

Comment: Hi @zus, You should accept the answer if it works for you. It will help others.